# Java Socket Connection Only Works for Certain IP Addresses

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have developed a two-part application in Java, with a server application and a client application. The client is built for Android. I start the server, run the Android client, and input the IP of the machine running the server into the client so it can connect.

Everything works fine, but *only* for certain IP addresses! When the address is for example "128.180.xxx.xxx", it will work, but if it's "128.180.xxx.xx" (with one fewer digits), the connection times out -- it can't render it.

Is this a known phenomenon? Or am I just rendering the IP incorrectly?
Thanks!

-----UPDATE------
By switching server actions from PC to Android, I was able to improve results -- but some PCs don't work; when on wifi, seemingly.
Here is the relevant code (ignore my sloppy error handling please):

**From the pc-side (acting as client)**

```
try {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String ipa = s.next();
    socket = new Socket(ipa, 8888);

    // Open input and output
    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

} catch (UnknownHostException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IOException e) {

     e.printStackTrace();

}
```

**From the Android side (acting as server)**

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
int portnum = 8888;
try {

    Log.v("client", "Server socket set up");
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portnum);

} catch (IOException e) { // If can't open port

    Log.v("client", "Could not listen on port " + portnum);
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);

} 
try {

    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    Log.v("client", "Client socket accepted.");
    Log.v("client", "Connect: attempting output stream initialization");
    dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    Log.v("client", "Connect: attempting input stream initialization");
    dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    Log.v("client","Connect: stream initialization complete");

} catch (IOException e) {

    Log.v("client", "Accept failed.");
    System.exit(1);

}
```

That is all the code that establishes the connection. Like I said, it works as a general case.

Comment: Assimiz is correct this will be a bug with your code/infrastructure, would you be willing to post a bit of info for your system (code/etc.).

Comment: I have added the code that establishes the connection (stripped of unrelated commands).

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way Java Sockets are out there with such a bug. In these cases I usually look for the simple dumb mistakes. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should ping the address "128.180.xxx.xx" just to see if it's actually available?

I recently coded a server/client application for computers on my own router network, specifying the router addresses as input to clients (192.168.0.xx) - no problem at all.

Comment: Turns out the Android was not able to render the IP of the PC, but switching it to have the PC seek out the Android server socket works -- at least usually. I'm still getting some issues when the PC is on wifi, which doesn't make sense to me. Your pinging idea was a good one, though, since it turns out that the reason some computers wont work is that they don't see the IP at all, for some reason.